# Grails Spring security for different form of authentication

Tags: spring, security, grails

I am currently using the grails and Spring security to implement the authenitcation. Not doing much customization , using the out of the box
and everything works fine for a user who lands into the auth.gsp where he will enter the username/password.
Now i have a requirement along with the normal flow, there will be a punch out from external site to our site.punch out will have username and passord provided as parameters.
In the punch out scenario user should not see the login screen and should get authenticated using the username/password provided in the url parameter.
Is this possible ?
How can I acheive both this in the same code

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do programmatic login. For example:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
....  
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
....
def login(String username, String password) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(params.username, params.password);
    User details = new User(params.username);
    token.setDetails(details);

    try {
        //doing actual authentication    
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
        log.debug("Login succeeded!");
        //setting principal in context
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        return true 
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        log.debug("Login failed")
        return false
    }
}
```

You can see some example here: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/java_web_application_security_part3

Hope this helps.